# How to pass variable outside loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've this variable:

```
String foo;

for(String links: Result){

    String myVariable="\n"+foo;
}

System.out.println(foo); //loop is giving error here..
```

How to use `foo` variable outside `for loop` in Java?

Comment: where is your variable 'foo' declared?

Comment: but what is foo? where it is initialized

Comment: Don't worry about that it's declared fine!

Comment: `String foo="something";` set a default value.I think the error you are getting is that you dint declare foo you only initialize it .

Comment: @singhakash: You have that backwards - foo is declared, but not initialized.

Comment: @BoltClock my mistake .The error you are getting is that you dint `initialize`  foo you only `declare`  it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to do

```
String foo=null; //or any default value you want your string to contain

for(String links: Result){

    String myVariable="\n"+foo;
}

System.out.println(foo);
```

your error is, you have declared a variable but not initialized it,

you can have a look at this [link](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2007/01/variable-might-not-have-been.html) to understand why this error was caused.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Okay.. Let me try this first. I'd accept your answer!

Comment: No dude.. I tried your answer.. It is getting only one Answer while declaring it.. Any possibilities by using `while` loop? What do you say?

Comment: if you can provide what is your expected output and what is your achieved output with your latest code, it will be easier to solve this

Comment: @Rajkumar are you still stuck?

Comment: Dude.. I'm want to get the result of that loop, but unfortunately ..I'm getting only one result. Here loop is not working.. :(

Comment: By using `StringBuilder` finally it's working!.. ThnX~

Answer (score 0):

Here, you could almost eliminate the for loop, entirely, and see the issue with the code in your post (as the `for` loop is not actually doing anything *to* `String foo`. So, as another user suggested, although you have declared `foo`, you have not done anything with the variable to give it a value.

So, your code is essentially:

```
String foo;    
System.out.println(foo);
```

Were your `for` loop to modify `foo`, then you would see a result:

```
String foo;

for(String links: Result){

    foo = foo + "a value added each time the loop iterates";
}

System.out.println(foo);
```